# Is there any way of printing Check boxes in Advanced PDF? (i mean the checkboxes itself not its value)

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript2.0

I want to make an advanced PDF printout in NetSuite. I want to print checkboxes (checked and unchecked) based on the values they have. I have no issue with the conditions, its just how to print the check box on Advanced pdf Printout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying library that NetSuite uses for rendering PDF files is [BFO Report Generator](https://bfo.com/products/report/)

BFO has an "[input](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/tags/input.html)" element which can display checkboxes. However it is only available in the Extended Edition - I am not sure which edition NetSuite licenses.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Java" checked="true"/>
```

If you don't need the PDF clickable checkbox, but just something that looks like one other possibilities you can try are to use the unicode checkbox characters (U+2610, U+2611 etc..), style a `div` like one or use a custom font.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've used unicode characters to display checkboxes whenever needed, since Netsuite PDF prints the checkboxes as "Yes" or "No".

Comment: @Jdg50 how did you do that? did u use the input element?

Comment: I believe I used a combination of if statements and the unicode characters listed above

Comment: i tried using &#x2611;  and &#9745; in div, span and even p, but nothing displayed.